# Error : Http failure during parsing in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm learning Angular, I want to display JSON data on HTML page.  The error is Http failure during parsing in Angular. I don't know why please tell me my mistake and give me links how to display JSON data with several types

**person.component.html**

```
<ul>

 <li *ngFor="let address of addresses">FirstName:{{ persons.addresses.City }}</li>
</ul>
```

person.json

```
[{
        "Addresses": [{ 

        "AddressId":101,
        "AddressTypes":["permanent", "temporary", "careof", "native"],
        "Address-L1":"space", 
        "Address-L2":"a.b.road",
        "Locality":"airoli(east)",
        "City":"Mumbai", 
        "State":"Maharashtra",
        "Country":"India",
        "Postalcode":400027
     }],

 "ContactNumbers" : 
[
    {

            "ContactID": 1,
            "ContactType": "Home",
            "CountryCode": "+91",
            "RegionCode": "022",
            "Number":2656568965

    }]    

}]
```

person-list.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
// import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';  // for debugging

export class Address{
  AddressId:number;
  City:string=""; 

}
/**
 * This class provides the NameList service with methods to read names and add names.
 */
@Injectable()
export class PersonListService {

  /**
   * Creates a new NameListService with the injected HttpClient.
   * @param {HttpClient} http - The injected HttpClient.
   * @constructor
   */
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  /**
   * Returns an Observable for the HTTP GET request for the JSON resource.
   * @return {string[]} The Observable for the HTTP request.
   */

  get(): Observable<Address[]>{
    console.log("Inside the get service")
    return this.http.get('app/person/person.json')

                 // .do(data => console.log('server data:', data))  // debug
                    .catch(this.handleError);

  }

  /**
    * Handle HTTP error
    */
  private handleError (error: any) {
    // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
    // We'd also dig deeper into the error to get a better message
    const errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
}
```

**person.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'sd-person',
  templateUrl: 'person.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['person.component.css']
})
export class PersonComponent implements OnInit {
  errorMessage: string;

addresses: Address[]=[];
constructor(public personListService:PersonListService){}
  ngOnInit() {
     // console.log(jwt.AuthConfig);
     this.getperson();
  }

  getperson(){

    this.personListService.get()
    .subscribe(
      addresses => this.addresses = addresses,
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
    );
    console.log(this.persons);
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

That is technically invalid JSON because of the trailing comma after "Mumbai"

It should be

```
[{"Addresses": [{ 
        "AddressId":101,
        "City":"Mumbai" 
         }]
}]
```

**EDIT**

Following the update, that is also invalid, as it needs to be wrapped in an object, like so:

```
{
    "Addresses": [{

        "AddressId": 101,
        "AddressTypes": ["permanent", "temporary", "careof", "native"],
        "Address-L1": "space",
        "Address-L2": "a.b.road",
        "Locality": "airoli(east)",
        "City": "Mumbai",
        "State":"Maharashtra",
        "Country": "India",
        "Postalcode": 400027
    }],

    "ContactNumbers": [{

        "ContactID": 1,
        "ContactType": "Home",
        "CountryCode": "+91",
        "RegionCode": "022",
        "Number": 2656568965

    }]

}
```

This will create a single object, containing 2 arrays: "Addresses", and "ContactNumbers"

Comment: @VinitMapari There must be some other error in the JSON. Can you please edit your question to include the full JSON file?

Comment: @VinitMapari I've just updated the answer following your updated JSON

Comment: I have updated and check and please tell me error I think error in calling on html page tell me your opinion

Comment: @VinitMapari Yep, I updated my answer, please take a look. Anytime it mentions error in parsing, it will be because of invalid JSON

Comment: how should i call in html if i want to call country in address array please help me 
 <li *ngFor="let address of addresses">FirstName:{{ persons.addresses.City }}</li></ul> is it right

Comment: In your subscribe, you will need to change it to: `response => this.addresses = response.Addresses,` (note that it is case sensitive, so because your JSON uses upper case A, you must do the same in your code). Then in your html, just change it to `{{ address.City }}`

Comment: Error Property 'Addresses' does not exist on type 'Address[]' on this line  response => this.addresses = response.Addresses,  on ***response.Addresses,***line

Comment: That's because you've typed your response as an `Observble<Address[]>`, where as in reality it returns an object that contains a property called `Addresses` (which is an `Address[]`), and one called `ContactNumbers`

Comment: Can you make the correction and send me that code as  you said above I have changed it as you said but still it gives me same  error sorry for that please sir send me corrected code

Comment: If you create a StackBlitz that reproduces the error, I'll fix it, and send you the fixed URL (even if you have the hardcode in the JSON into the service for now  instead of making an HTTP request)

Comment: No. As I mentioned in my comment, if you're willing to add the code to a StackBlitz, then I will fix it.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aduxhy?file=src/app/app.component.html Bear in mind, i couldn't get the JSON from your HTTP endpoint, so I've just mocked it using Observable.of

Comment: please modify as above link or just tell me where to write addresses means as you said earlier "That's because you've typed your response as an Observble<Address[]>, where as in reality it returns an object that contains a property called Addresses (which is an Address[])," so i have just replace Observble<Address[]> with Observble<Addresses> right?

Comment: Have a look at the change I made within the service, and the change I made within getPersons

Comment: Thank you so much sir one last request i have added json can correct the code as per json so it will help me to build further jsons just one help https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4jdhyo?file=src/app/person.json

Comment: Hi can you solve this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50705776/error-is-error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-firstname-of-undefined?noredirect=1#comment88422739_50705776

Answer (score 1):

In your **person-list.service.ts** file convert the response into JSON.

Map the response to JSON.

```
return this.http.get('app/person/person.json')
    .map(response => response.json())
    // .do(data => console.log('server data:', data))
    .catch(this.handleError);
```

Or else you can convert the response from component itself.