# error is ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'FirstName' of undefined

Tags: angular

I am learning angular. Here I am making demographic component as a tag and it is going to use in person component. It shows me error as demographic.component.html:3 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'FirstName' of undefined
If any one want to solve it I have uploaded it on stackblitz link is 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6uhfoz

person.json

```
{
    "Demographics" : { 
            "ProfileId":1,
            "FirstName":"vinit"
           }

}
```

demographic.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as jwt from 'angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt';
import { CardModule } from 'primeng/card';
import { ScrollPanelModule } from 'primeng/scrollpanel';
import { PersonListService,Person} from './person-list.service';

@Component({ 
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'sd-demographic',
  templateUrl: 'demographic.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['demographic.component.css']
})
export class DemographicComponent implements OnInit {
    errorMessage: string;
    persons: Person;
    constructor(public personListService:PersonListService){}
    ngOnInit() {
       // console.log(jwt.AuthConfig);
       this.getperson();
    }

    getperson(){

      this.personListService.getDemographic()
      .subscribe(
       resp => this.persons = resp.Persons,

        //resp => this.addresses = resp.Addresses,
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
      );
 }
}
```

demographic.component.html

```
 <ul>
        <li><b>Demographics</b></li>
        <li>FirstName:{{ persons.FirstName }}</li>
    </ul>
```

person.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as jwt from 'angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt';
import { PersonListService} from './person-list.service';

/**
 * This class represents the lazy loaded PersonComponent.
 */
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'sd-person',
  templateUrl: 'person.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['person.component.css']
})
export class PersonComponent implements OnInit {
  /*errorMessage: string;

*/
constructor(public personListService:PersonListService){}
  ngOnInit() {
     // console.log(jwt.AuthConfig);
     //this.getperson();
  }


 }
```

person-list.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    // import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';  // for debugging
    export class Person{

      ProfileId:number;
      FirstName:string="";
    }

    }

    /**
     * This class provides the NameList service with methods to read names and add names.
     */
    @Injectable()
    export class PersonListService {

      /**
       * Creates a new NameListService with the injected HttpClient.
       * @param {HttpClient} http - The injected HttpClient.
       * @constructor
       */
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

      /**
       * Returns an Observable for the HTTP GET request for the JSON resource.
       * @return {string[]} The Observable for the HTTP request.
       */
      getDemographic(): Observable<{Persons: Person}>{
        console.log("Inside the get service")
        return this.http.get('app/person/person.json')

                     // .do(data => console.log('server data:', data))  // debug
                        .catch(this.handleError);

      }
```

person.component.html

```
<p-tabView>
    <p-tabPanel header="Demographics">

        <sd-demographic></sd-demographic>

    </p-tabPanel>
</p-tabView>
```

Comment: do you have a stackblitz

Comment: yes I have stackblitz should i upload code

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6uhfoz?file=src%2Fperson%2Fperson.json

Comment: in demographic component when you console.log(resp) what can you see?

Comment: same thing can you please solve it on stackblitz i have given link

Comment: same thing? what that actually means? are you seeing data?

Comment: Why are you doing `{Persons: Person}`? Where is `Persons` coming from? That key does not exist in your JSON

Answer (score 2):

```
 <ul>
        <li><b>Demographics</b></li>
        <li>FirstName:{{ persons.FirstName }}</li>
    </ul>
```

When angular initializes your template persons stills undefined untill the following it's executed:

```
    getperson(){

      this.personListService.getDemographic()
      .subscribe(
       resp => this.persons = resp.Persons,

        //resp => this.addresses = resp.Addresses,
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
      );
 }
```

Since HTTP it's asynchronous persons will be resolved until the get is completed and your template will be able to show it.

What you have to do is to use the [safe operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator) or ngIf on your template.

```
 <ul>
        <li><b>Demographics</b></li>
        <li>FirstName:{{ persons?.FirstName }}</li>
    </ul>
```

or

```
 <ul *ngIf="persons">
        <li><b>Demographics</b></li>
        <li>FirstName:{{ persons?.FirstName }}</li>
    </ul>
```