# Angular and Stackblitz

Tags: angular, stackblitz

This link [mon appli dans Stackblitz](https://angular-wp77ob.stackblitz.io) shows a small application (from the angular 7 doc) on stackbliz. I made some changes that I later canceled but it seems that there are traces and the application does not work. I deduce that it is probably a question of cache. My question is this: how to reset the stackblitz cache ?
NOTA: An exact copy of the application works perfectly in another Stackblitz session ([working session of Stackblitz](https://angular-bncgz4.stackblitz.io))

Comment: Error message is:
[message: Http failure during parsing for ](https://angular-wp77ob.stackblitz.io/assets/config.json)

my researches online allowed me to note that this problem is perhaps identified, the page below evokes the subject

[Http failure during parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50655235/error-http-failure-during-parsing-in-angular)

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved. I deleted and recreated my config.json file and the error disappeared. This file was probably coded incorrectly, but it is difficult to check, Stackblitz not giving, unless I'm mistaken, access to the type of encoding files.